# How to access model data in MVC without Html helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This works

```
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Data, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

This next line doesn't like "model=>model.Data"

```
  <img src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(model => model.Data)" height="80" />
```

Comment: @lrb 'name model does not exist in current context'

Comment: Model.Data or @Model.Data??

Comment: @lrb you are right Model.Data is good, I tried model.Data

Answer (score 1):

```
  @if (Model.Data != null)
  {
                    <img src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Data))" height="80" />
  }
```